# Change permissions on symbolic link

Tags: symlink, programming

I'm starting in programming with multiple exercices and I don't know how to change my link permission (`lrwxrwxrwx` to `lrwxr-xr-x`).

I have already searched solutions from Google and Youtube but nothing happen when I try their solutions. Can someone help?

---

ok my bad my adblock was on.

My problem is the last line with " test6 -> test0 "

[image: My result]
[image: The requested result]

Comment: IMHO you can't . You can change them on source file/directory

Comment: The  link permissions are not really used. Permissions set on the file the symlink points to will be used to restrict access. What are you trying to accomplish with a chmod of the symlink perms?

Comment: You can change only the linked file permission, symlinks will be always lrwxrwxrwx which doesn't mean everybody has full permission on the file.

Comment: I have to reproduce this results (LRWXR-XR-X), knowing that I have no starting point, where can i put a photo to show you ?

Comment: @Raph, edit your answer and click on the icon like small photo.

Comment: I would like to but I don't have the icon

Comment: Raph, when you started the exercises were you advised to use a particular system? What you want is not possible under Linux, but [is possible](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/716388/100397) with something like OpenBSD

Answer (score 2):

If you have not already done so, reinstall the system with OpenBSD, and
then you may use `chmod -h` to change the permissions of the link:

```
$ touch foo
$ ln -s foo bar
$ stat -f '%p %N' foo bar
100644 foo
120755 bar
$ chmod -h 700 bar
$ stat -f '%p %N' foo bar
100644 foo
120700 bar
```

Otherwise, if you are on an operating system that does not support the
above, you are out of luck. For example, `chmod(1)` on a Linux may contain
something along the lines of:

> chmod never changes the permissions of symbolic links; the chmod
> system call cannot change their permissions. This is not a problem
> since the permissions of symbolic links are never used.

Answer (score -1):

to assign "LRWXR-XR-X" permissions you can use the command (on the directory with the file):

`chmod test6 755`

Comment: This changes the permissions on the file `test0`. Permissions on the symlink `test6` are unchanged. The OP asked how to change the perms on the symlink itself.

Comment: I see, sorry I didn't get that part, as far as I know symlinks behave like the actual file, so it should have the same permissions.

Comment: It's always worth testing a solution before posting it.

Comment: The symlink just needs to have more permissive settings than the target. 0777 is the most permissive so that is what the symlink is set at. Access to the target is ultimately determined by the target's permissions.